# Laravel multiple show functions within the same controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have a problem with making a newswebsite. I have multiple index functions to load in category views. inside of each view i want to be able to go to an article page by using the show function. how do i use multiple show functions within one controller.

these are 2 of the 8 index funtions i use.

```
public function indexbusiness()
{
    $artikels =  Artikel::where('category_id', '4')->get();
    return view('pages.business')->with('artikels', $artikels);
}

public function indextech()
{
    $artikels =  Artikel::where('category_id', '5')->get();
    return view('pages.tech')->with('artikels', $artikels);
}
```

i want to add show functions like this

```
 public function showbusiness($id)
{
    $artikel = Artikel::find($id);
    return view(pages.show);
}
```

can someone help me out on this one?

all help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to have all of these functions in one controller instead of just using multiple controllers i.e. is there a specific benefit with your application?

Comment: Can't you create one index function and add the category slug in the url?

Comment: because here at my internship they said it was unnecessary  to create 8 different controllers for each category. they said i could do it with just 1 or 2. so im trying to figure out how you can do multiple show functions in one controller

Comment: is it still possible to edit the one controller i've added and add 7 others for all the other categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go about this from a different approach. You can use just one controller for this and accept a category as a parameter. For example in your routes:

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('/articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::get('/articles/{category}', 'ArticlesController@index');
```

Within your controller, you would then have one index method. For example:

**ArticleController**

```php
public function index($category)
{
    if($slug) {
        $articles = Article::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($category) {
            $query->where('slug', $category);
        })->get();

        return view('pages'.$category)->with('articles', $articles);
    }

    $articles = Article::all();

    return view('pages.articles')->with('articles);
}
```

That will allow you to load which ever articles you want by the category. This approach makes the assumption that you have a relationship of `category` on the Article model and that the `Category` model has a slug value.

For this example, you could then visit `/articles/tech` or `/articles/business`.

You can then do the same approach with the `show` method. For this, your routes might look like the following:

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('/articles/{category}/{article}', 'ArticlesController@show');
```

Your controller could then be

**ArticleController**

```php
public function show($category, $id)
{
    $article = Article::whereHas('category', function (query) use ($category) {
        $query->where('slug', $category);
    })->where('id', $id)->first();

    return view('pages.show')->with('article', $article);
}
```

You might need to adapt the above to fit your specific use case, but the principle is generally the same.

Comment: thanks for this answer. this might be a little hard implementing because i am still a beginner but i will approve your answer when i succeed.